# Rounded Border Corner

Tags: css

I'm wondering about how to make the top-border like the red line on the picture below? I've tried `border-radius`, but I can't figure out how to round the bottom part of the top-border.

[image]

Comment: show what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `:before` to create a pseudo-element that you can style, as it is only used for presentation, so having an empty element would be unnecessarily verbose.

Here’s an example of how this could be done:

```css
.splitter {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 0;
}
  .splitter:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px / 70px;
  }

.myContent {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="splitter">
  <div class="myContent">
    <h1>React or Angular</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum Mollit qui sunt consequat deserunt exercitation veniam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which can also be seen working on JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/hoqizajada/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible with a single div. However, you can place a div above it and trick with `border-radius`.

```css
.inbox {
  width: 200px;
}
#top-border {  
  border: red 4px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#test{
  padding: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top-border" class="inbox"></div>
  <div id="test" class="inbox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/pofolanuje/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete code, hope this helps you;

```css
.container{
  width:320px;
  height:520px;
  background:#fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
.border-red{
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="border-red">

</div>
</div>
```